# How to report spam sent through my website contact form without blocking it?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, forms

Despite the Google captcha protection I receive some spam from my website contact forms.

I want to report these spams but without blocking my contact form address.

Explaination: when somebody send a mail from the contact form, the mail goes first to my website server (contact@mywebsite.com adress), and is automatically redirected to MyPrivateAdress@gmail.com. So I can't use the Gmail "spam report" option to report the spam@spam.com without blocking contact@mywebsite.com address.

Any idea how to report that kind of contact form's spams?

Comment: Sorry but this question appears to be duplicate. There is various questions and answers regarding mail forms all over Pro Webmasters, for example you may find [Can randomly generated field names helpful](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/can-randomly-generated-field-names-help-avoid-spam-bots) as well as [making your site anti bot](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot). To avoid future disappointment on the Stack Exchange network please ensure you read the help center on the stack your posting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is basically only two options to do anything about it:

1. Look up the management contact for the ip sending spam, (the `whois` utility can do it for you,) and send them an email and hopefully the spammer will be suspended.
2. Block the IPs/IP ranges that is sending the spam from your contact form.

Comment: The third option which is real life observation. Reporting it is a waste of time as the source for this stuff is usually completely outside of anyone's jurisdiction.

Comment: In my experience the ISPs that owns the IP range often suspends them, but some don't care, sure.