# Best way to block "comment spam" postings to web forms?

Tags: spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make your site anti-bot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot)

I have a custom web form on my PHP-based site.

Recently it is getting a regular stream of **comment-spam** postings from a few specific IP addresses.

**Question:**  What is a good way to block a small set of blacklisted IP addresses from accessing my site?

I was thinking it should be possible using **.htaccess** to respond with status code 403 (Forbidden) for all HTTP requests from the blacklisted IP addresses, ... but I am not sure exactly how to do that.

If anyone knows the **.htaccess** syntax needed to accomplish this, ... please let me know.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I use Akismet to block comment spam in my Wordpress log. (Almost all comments are spam, but I still get an appreciate proper comments.)  This service can be used by other comment streams.  Plugins are available for various applications.  The code is PHP and should be looking at.

Comment: original poster wasnt asking about WP although akisment is a very useful tool

Comment: No need to downrate, as Akismet provides an API. There are two stand-alone PHP implementations listed on http://akismet.com/development/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible trick is to create a form element that you hide with css, then validate your form, if that form element has content in it you can reject the form as a normal user would not have been able to fill it in therefore it must most likely be spam.

In htaccess you would have to fully block those IP's to my knowledge, but to block an IP from browsing your site, add the following to your HTAccess file

```
order allow,deny
deny from 127.0.0.1
allow from all`
```

where 127.0.0.1 is the IP you want to block, to block extra IP's just duplicate the deny line and edit the IP to match

Comment: I find the hidden (with CSS) element very effective. However, many of these browser extensions that auto populate form fields can auto populate your hidden field as well and so flagging the submission as possible spam! You can try using an obscure field name to prevent the browser from auto populating this field, but then robots might be less likely to populate it as well?!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to get rid of comment spam is using a [CAPTCHA](http://captcha.net/) system. There are plugins for vaious systems including PHP that make implementing them very easy. This is one of the techniques used by this site.

With regard to blocking IP addresses the best form of defence is a good firewall. Simply add the offending IPs to the firewall's blacklist. That said blocking IPs won't stop the issue as many spammers are using botnets these days that use different IP addresses for each attack.