# What's a good way to keep spam out of 'anonymous' submission websites?

Tags: spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make your site anti-bot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot)

I'm trying to do everything I can to prevent spammers from just pasting crap all over my forum websites.  People get incentivized by video games and porn sites and who-all to just paste their ads all over the Internet.  I feel like just locking it all up and requiring admin approval for every account.

On the other hand, I don't even like registering for websites.  A lot of times, I just go out on a 'do-gooder' mission, trying to hook somebody up with an answer to an extremely difficult question.  I run into 3 or 4 forums I've never been to in my life..., just wanting to post on them cause they're at the top of google.  I don't want to submit my information to them, though.  I don't know or trust them, and I don't want to go through validation steps.  So, the Internet just goes without the valuable information that I have, sometimes.  I don't want people to just avoid my website because they aren't in the mood to hassle with sign-ups.

Naturally, I've tried Captcha and validation e-mails, but spammers are generally smart enough to get by these.  Are there some other good techniques?

Comment: @dan Then merge it!  I don't know where this other question is!

Comment: At the top of this page you should see a "Possible Duplicate: [Make your site anti-bot?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot)" message which includes the link to the original question on this topic.